# "Exactly-once" Spark Streaming: start streaming Kafka from offset limiting range for first batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Is if possible to receive first batch in a certain range starting from defined offset? This seems the only solution to recover after Exception and guarantee transactionality to re-apply rdd if it was partially processed to database.

Comment: Are we talking about Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov rdd batch transformed to dataframe and aggregated data applied to certain key in NoSQL. I want to make sure that batch (and thus aggregate) applied to a record exactly once. so when I start processing from earliest make sure record in NoSQL knows which aggregate range been already applied